# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

Tags: java, android, aws-sdk, amazon-simpledb

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.mickey4real.helloworld, PID: 19318

- Hi, I trying to make an android app that would connect to Amazon's SimpleDB. I get the following error when trying to run a program that performs a SelectRequest from my SimpleDB Domain. Please can anyone help me.

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.(InternalConfig.java:43)

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java)

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.(InternalConfig.java:304)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95)

at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.(ClientConfiguration.java:61)

at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.(AmazonSimpleDBClient.java:133)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.AWSConnection.getSimpleDB(AWSConnection.java:23)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.Login.getAllUsernames(Login.java:115)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.Login.onClick(Login.java:169)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mickey4real.helloworld-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.(InternalConfig.java:43)

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java)

at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.(InternalConfig.java:304)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134)

at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95)
 
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.(ClientConfiguration.java:61)

at com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient.(AmazonSimpleDBClient.java:133)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.AWSConnection.getSimpleDB(AWSConnection.java:23)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.Login.getAllUsernames(Login.java:115)

at com.example.mickey4real.helloworld.Login.onClick(Login.java:169)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)

at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

**Here is my code for connecting to SimpleDB**

```
public static AmazonSimpleDB getSimpleDB(){
    if(sdb == null){
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(getProperties().getProperty("accessKey"), getProperties().getProperty("secretKey"));
        sdb = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
    }
    return sdb;
}
```

I try to perform a SelectRequest

```
`SelectRequest selectRequest=  new SelectRequest("select username from domain").withConsistentRead(true);`

`List<com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.model.Item> items  = AWSConnection.getSimpleDB().select(selectRequest).getItems();`
```

But I keep getting this annoying error and I don't know why. Please can someone help me.

Lastly here are my dependencies from my Build.gradle file. Please can someone help me? I am so confused.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'}
```

**Here is my Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mickey4real.helloworld">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SiteList">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlarmList">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Form">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SiteMap">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SiteInfo">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Home">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest ?

Comment: Please fix the indenting on your stacktrace so that isn't pushed all the way off frame.

Comment: I think the problem is not in your code. Issue raised because of external jars that were added to your build path. Take them of clean project and add them again.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me quickly, I appreciate the help. I tried what you said @ShreeKrishna but it did not work. I keep getting the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. I simple had to include the missing JAR file to my dependencies. In this case, it was: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.0 and the error vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson Library is not found: add this compile line to your gradle (app module):

`compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'`

Please check also which is the last version of jackson library